# Positioning of an image relative to a div within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a page that displays the time.
    The ':' of the font i'm using is ugly so i want to replace it with an image.
    However when the time goes from example from 9:59 to 10:00 there are spacing issues.
    Here is some of my code:

```
.image{
    position: absolute;
    width:30px; height:90px; 
    background-image: url("2dots.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:50%;margin-top:30px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-49px;
    z-index:-1;
}
#time { 
    font-size: 99px; 
    width:300px;
    left:50%; 
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:-40px;
}
<div id="time"><div class="image"></div></div>
function updateClock() //updates time ever second inside #time every second
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't want to juggle with the positioning like that.

You should just set the `.image` to `display: inline-block`, then place it in between the hours and minutes:

```
.image{
    width:30px;
    height:90px; 
    background-image: url("2dots.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:50%;
}
```

```
<div id="time">
    <span id="hours">12</span>
    <div class="image"></div>
    <span id="minutes">30</span>
</div>
```

Then, just set the current time's hours / minutes in the proper spans.
Of course, you can just add seconds after it, if you need.

However, a different option would be to use a `<span>` that displays a different font, just for the colon:

```css
span{
    font-family: Arial;
}
.colon{
    font-family: Tahoma;
}
```

```html
<div id="time">
    <span id="hours">12</span><span class="colon">:</span><span id="minutes">30</span>
</div>
(Normal colon : )
```

Or, from [@Paulie_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2802040/paulie-d)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604885/positioning-of-an-image-relative-to-a-div-within-a-div/26604971#comment41822786_26604971):

```css
span{
    font-family: Arial;
}
#hours:after{
    content: ':';
    font-family: Tahoma;
}
```

```html
<div id="time">
    <span id="hours">12</span><span id="minutes">30</span>
</div>
(Normal colon : )
```

Comment: Even better, use an `:after` pseudo element on `#hours` and use the image as a background. More semantic too and keeps "styling" in the CSS where it belongs.

Comment: I'll suggest `:after`, but using css, instead of a background image.